# Scopes & Closures in Mocha/Chai Assertions

Tags: node.js, scope, mocha.js, chai

I'm writing some tests for an express app and I am wondering how to properly access a variable in one assertion block from another. The variable I am trying to access is `this.token = res.body.token`

Whenever I try to access it, it comes up undefined (other than when accessing it within the beforeEach block). How can I access this variable? I need to use the token to set the headers in my test for my POST request.

Code:

```
describe('CRUD: tests the GET & POST routes', () => {
  beforeEach(done => {
    chai.request('localhost:3000')
    .post('/app/signup')
    .send({ email: 'meow@test.com', password: 'testpass' })
    .end((err, res) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      this.token = res.body.token; // this variable holds a token when accessed within this scope (tested it with node debugger)
      done();
    });
  });

  it('should create with a new cat with a POST request', (done) => {
      chai.request('localhost:3000')
      .post('/app/cats')
      .set('token', this.token) // when accessed here, it is undefined...
      .send({ username: 'cat_user' })
      .end((err, res) => {
        expect(err).to.eql(null);
        expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        expect(res.body.name).to.eql('test cat');
        expect(res.body).to.have.property('_id');
        done();
      });
    });
```

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of my terminal in node debug mode. As you can see, when it hits the first debugger break and `_token` is accessed, it contains the token. In the next debugger break, however, it comes up empty... (maybe that means something else in the debugger?)

[image: app in debugger mode]

Answer (score 2):

You can move your variable to the scope of your `describe`.

```
describe('CRUD: tests the GET & POST routes', () => {
  let _token;

  beforeEach(done => {
    chai.request('localhost:3000')
    .post('/app/signup')
    .send({ email: 'meow@test.com', password: 'testpass' })
    .end((err, res) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      _token = res.body.token; // this variable holds a token when accessed within this scope (tested it with node debugger)
      done();
    });
  });

  it('should create with a new cat with a POST request', (done) => {
      chai.request('localhost:3000')
      .post('/app/cats')
      .set('token', _token) // when accessed here, it is undefined...
      .send({ username: 'cat_user' })
      .end((err, res) => {
        expect(err).to.eql(null);
        expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        expect(res.body.name).to.eql('test cat');
        expect(res.body).to.have.property('_id');
        done();
      });
    });
```

You should read this to understand `this`: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Comment: I tried that, but ```_token``` or whatever other variable I use comes up undefined as well. Which makes no sense to me since it's defined when accessed inside that beforeEach block.

Comment: Are you sure, that `res.body.token` is not undefined?

Comment: Yeah, it comes up as a 120 character string.

Comment: I added a screenshot, mind taking a look? Maybe my explanation wasn't very clear.